# Prove that $(a_n)_{n\geq1}$ is convergent, given that: $ a_n - \frac{1}{m}\leq a_m\leq \frac{m}{n}; $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Prove that $(a_n)_{n\geq1}$ is convergent, given that:

$ a_n - \frac{1}{m}\leq a_m\leq \frac{m}{n};   \forall m,n\in \mathbb{N}^* , m \geq n $

I need a hint to solve this problem.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $m \ge 1$, we have $a_1 -1 \le a_1 -1/m \le a_m$. Hence $\{a_n\}$ is bounded below.

Taking $m=2n$, we get $a_{2m} \le 2$ for $m \in \mathbb N$. Taking $m=2n+1$, we get that the sequence is bounded above. Finally, it is bounded. Hence it has a limit point.

Consider a limit point $l$ of the sequence, $n \in \mathbb N$ and a subsequence $\{a_{i(m)}\}$ converging to $l$. From the inequality

$$a_n -\frac{1}{i(m)} \le a_{i(m)}$$ which is valid for $i(m)\ge n$, we get by letting $m \to \infty$

$$a_n \le l$$ for any $n \in \mathbb N$. Which means that the sequence is less or equal to any of its limit point. From there we get that the set of limit points has only one element and therefore that the sequence converges.

Comment: Nice! Once we know the sequence is bounded we may proceed as follows: take $\liminf_{m\to\infty}$ in the first inequality, and then take $\limsup_{n\to\infty}$. We get that limsup is not greater that liminf, hence lim exists (and is finite since the sequence is bounded). This is essentially what you did but expressed in a fancy language of limsup and liminf.

Comment: Thank you a lot!